# Read and manipulate xlsx file from local storage and extract some of the values from cells into .txt and .csv files

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlrd, pyxll

## Read excel file and extract the details into a new .txt file using openpyxl

I am new to openpyxl, just started yesterday. I need to extract the data from the excel file from my local storage that excel file have 500+ rows and 50+ columns. I want to extract some specific cells or columns or rows into the .txt and .csv file.

I cannot find where is the mistake what to add in this code

````
from openpyxl import *
import os    

path = 'F:\\mis'
files = [i for i in os.listdir(path) if i.endswith('.xlsx')]

for f in files:
     wb = load_workbook(os.path.join(path, f))
     for row in wb['newxl.xlsx'].rows:
         with open(row[2].value+'.txt', 'w') as outfile:
              outfile.write(row[0].value)```
````

Comment: You want to extract rows or columns?

Comment: @RobinSage  I want to extract some of the data from cells using column name for the purpose of updating in our company website

Comment: @RobinSage could you see my last comment

Comment: What do you think `wb['newxl.xlsx']` is?

Comment: @CharlieClark wb['newxl.xlsx'] means ?? could you explain

Comment: It's your code, you tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER

```
import openpyxl
import csv
      
roster = openpyxl.load_workbook('roster.xlsx')
sheet = roster.active
col = csv.writer(open("new_roster.csv",'w',newline=""))

st_id = int(input("Enter student ID: "))
for row in sheet.rows:
    if row[0].value == st_id:
        col.writerow([cell.value for cell in row])
print("File created!")
```

UPDATE 2

This is how you can get the values from a specific column:

```
import openpyxl
roster = openpyxl.load_workbook('roster.xlsx')  
sheet = roster.active
col = sheet['B']  

for x in range(len(col)): 
    print(col[x].value)
```

UPDATE 3

Return specific values from column:

```
import openpyxl

roster = openpyxl.load_workbook('roster.xlsx')  
sheet = roster.active

col = sheet['B']  # <-- change the column according to your file
val = input("Enter value: ")
for c in range(len(col)): 
    if val == col[c].value:
        print(f'Found {col[c].value}!')
```

Comment: I want to extract the details from existing xlsx file from local storage

Comment: I think that's what I did. I created a sample xlsx file and extracted some data. Or maybe I didn't quite understand the question.

Comment: partially i got the answer

Comment: but i need to append these into .txt and csv file

Comment: Just updated the answer. Lemme know if that works for ya.

Comment: it appends all the data from the excel file but i need to extract  some specific cells and rows using column name .

Comment: Sorry. I forgot. Updated it again...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240702/discussion-between-mohanraj-m-and-robin-sage).

Comment: i just need some specific cells from the row using column name. that's my requirement

Comment: Just updated the answer. If you find it useful, please upvote it and check it as answered. Thanks!

Comment: It prints all the row values of the  given column of the excel sheet.

Comment: It prints all the row values of the  given column of the excel sheet.
but what my need is i want to extract some some specific fields'
for example, If we have an excel sheet with 5 columns(id, name, roll_number, dob, blood_group)  and 5 rows (imagine any 5 dummy data's in these field). here i need id no 3 ' s name and dob how to get those the user is need to choose the option of what bassed on the search (for ex) with the column 2nd named name 4th rows dob and id we need to get

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Nothing is printed in this update just getting input.
i need not only one columns value i need some specific column values for each row.
 if you are free can we have a call i'll explain well for you

Comment: Check the update. You need to change the column based on the file you have there. It should work fine. You have all the code you need to get it to work. If you find the answer I provided satisfactory, please upvote and check it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel("F:\\mis\\CASHE.xlsx")
cus_id=input("Please enter your customer id:")
cashe=['customer_id', 'customer_name', 'login_email_id', 'login_source', 'New_date', 'customer_status_name']

if cus_id == '':
    df1=df[cashe]
else:
    df1=df[cashe].loc[df['customer_id']==int(cus_id)]

df1.to_csv('Cashe1.csv')
print("csv printed with values")
```